# input listeners in Ext.panel.Panel

Tags: extjs

hello i am want input function for click button in keyboard on Ext.panel.Panel, i do this for:
 **extend: 'Ext.window.Window':**

```
Ext.define('Container', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias : 'widget.container',

title : 'book',
 listeners: {
    afterrender: function (thisForm, options) {
        this.keyMap = Ext.create(
            'Ext.util.KeyMap',
            this.el,
            [
                {
                    key: 13,
                    fn: function () {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('title', 'you click enter');
                    },
                    scope: this
                }
            ]
        );
    }
},
```

but when i do this on **Ext.panel.Panel** it not work:

```
Ext.define('doc', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
alias: 'widget.doc',
     listeners: {
    afterrender: function (thisForm, options) {
        this.keyMap = Ext.create(
            'Ext.util.KeyMap',
            this.el,
            [
                {
                    key: 13,
                    fn: function () {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('title', 'enter click');
                    },
                    scope: this
                }
            ]
        );
    }
},
```

Comment: Is there any error output in your developer tools' console?

Comment: There is nothing output in the console.